# Why hibernate does not write any information in table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have such situation:
There are a few groups of POJO classes, each with one parent. Each group serves to be working with some recording of data - to the XML with the help of JAXB and to the database with the help of Hibernate. A simplified version of my working code is:

```
public static abstract class Habit{
    String habitName;
    /* constructors */
    /* getter & setter */
}
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "habit")
public static class DBHabit extends Habit{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "habit_name")
    public String getHabitName() {
        return habitName;
    }

    public void setHabitName(String habitName) {
        this.habitName = habitName;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name = "habit")
public static class XmlHabit extends Habit{
    @XmlElement
    public String getHabitName() {
        return habitName;
    }

    public void setHabitName(String habitName) {
        this.habitName = habitName;
    }
}
public static abstract class Person{
    int age;
    String name;
    List<Habit> habits;


    /* Constructor */
    /* Getters & Setters */

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Habit> getHabits() {
        return habits;
    }

    public void setHabits(List<Habit> habits) {
        this.habits = habits;
    }
}

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "person")
public static class DBPerson extends Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "age")
    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = DBHabit.class)
    @Override
    public List<Habit> getHabits() {
        return habits;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHabits(List<Habit> friends) {
        this.habits = habits;
    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "age",
        "name",
        "habits"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "state")
public static class XmlPerson extends Person{
    @Override
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public int getAge() {
        return super.getAge();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAge(int age) {
        super.setAge(age);
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        super.setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "friends")
    public List<Habit> getHabits() {
        return super.getHabits();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHabits(List<Habit> habits) {
        super.setHabits(habits);
    }
}
```

I have problems with working with Hibernate. Thought I wrote that I expect the recording of DBHabit.class in targetEntity, hibernate does not record any information about habits, this table is always empty.
Please give me a hint, what can I make in such situation or advice, how I can make a similar abstract system like this for the writing in different ways.
Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of strange thing i noticed in your mapping:

- a `@OneToOne` mapping, backed by a `List<Habit>`. Why not directly Habit ?
- You annotate class with `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` but then you put the mapping annotation on accessor methods (you're issue might come from there).

Instead you could try to annotate the parent abstract class as `@MappedSuperclass`. This way, you do not have to redefine the accessor. Or if you do not wish to put hibernate annotations in the parent class, remove the `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` annotation.